# Linux Kernel: pausing other task_struct

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to pause a different task than the one on behalf of which the kernel is currently executing? To stop the current task, one can just set it to inactive and call schedule, but what about a different one?

What I have currently:

```
void disable_thread(struct task_struct *tsk) {

    if (tsk->state == TASK_RUNNING) {

        /*
         * A running task - mark it stopped and wait for it to be descheduled
         */

        tsk->state = TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE;
        wait_task_inactive(tsk, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);

    } else if (tsk->state == TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE || tsk->state == TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE) {

        /*
         *  // TODO: what to do with tasks already waiting for something else?
         */

    } else {

        /*
         * This task's state seems to indicate that it's dead, no need to disable it anymore.
         */
    }
}
```

Stopping a running thread seems to work this way, but what can we do if the thread is already waiting for something else (e.g. waiting to acquire a lock), to prevent it from restarting even if it would get the lock?

I'm implementing a security feature, and can give more context if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious if you finally solve the problem? In my mind, you could probably change the scheduler to avoid scheduling the task even when it is waken up.

Comment: This was a concept for my thesis (the question was posted after checking with my promotor). In the end, changing the scheduler would have taken us too far, so we decided to only implement our security feature for single core CPUs.